# How can I flag the first bar of the second last session with pinescript 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to plot something from the first bar of the second last session that is loaded on the graph.

Since the bar count per session varies and for example a monday can be preceded by a sunday, friday or thursday, and not every session covers the same amount of time, I find it hard to pinpoint the session that is preceding the last session.

I want an indicator that works on multiple tickers.

Tried calculating the bar_index by subtracting it from last_bar_index but when the second last session starts you don't know yet how many bars there will be in the last session.

Answer (score 0):

Try [session.isfirstbar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session.isfirstbar) and [session.islastbar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session.islastbar)
You can also use `session.isfirstbar_regular` and `session.islastbar_regular`

Something like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator('session', overlay = true)

plotshape(
  session.isfirstbar,
  text       = 'isfirstbar',
  color      = color.gray,
  textcolor  = color.white,
  style      = shape.labelup,
  size       = size.small,
  location   = location.belowbar)
plotshape(
  session.islastbar,
  text       = 'islastbar',
  color      = color.gray,
  textcolor  = color.white,
  style      = shape.labeldown,
  size       = size.small,
  location   = location.abovebar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I want this to only show on 1 session; not the last session on the graph but the second last. Any suggestions for that part?